# Quick question about my query(AVG, OVER, GROUP BY problem)

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I try using AVG and OVER to get 7 days average but I got stuck.
I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Would you help me to find the problem?

```
SELECT
    dt
    , SUM(purchase_amount) as total_amount
    , AVG(SUM(purchase_amount))
    OVER(ORDER BY dt 
        ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as seven_day_avg
FROM purchase_log
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt
```

```
ERROR:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'(ORDER BY dt row between 6 preceding and current row) as seven_day_avg ' at line 5
```

Comment: MySQL added window functions in version 8.0 you are probably using an older version

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, That's the Problem... Thanks for your quick answer!